# How to keep list insertion order when saving to db using Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm using spring-boot and I have an Entity class (class A) that contains a list of elements from a different class (class B).

In general, the list contains list of orders, and there is no timestamp.

I want to save an object of class A to MySql DB while keeping the insertion order of the list.
Is that possible?

Thanks,
Avi

```
@Entity
public class A {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<B> orders;
}

@Entity
public class B {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String order;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. Please try using **@OrderColumn** annotation above the List you want to keep order. Here is my example.

```
....

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderColumn
private List<B> orders;
```

for more info, I think this link can help you.

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/order-column.html

Hope my answer can help you:)

Comment: The @OrderColumn worked but only on a new table. it fails if I apply it on an existing table. Is there something to do about that?